# Is CFRelease necessary here to prevent a leak?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

So I've heard that `new` `alloc` and `copy` create new memory on the heap that you are responsible for. I want to make sure that is also the case with a C-function in Core Graphics:

`myIvar=CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage));`

Does this mean that I *must* release it later like:

`CFRelease(myIvar);`

In other words, **if I re-assign `myIvar` later *without* the release statement, it will cause a leak?**

Regarding the comments, I've uploaded this screenshot:

[image]

The commented-out line works fine. Prior to this line I have `m_parsedImage = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage));` which also works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any function with Copy or Create in the name, by convention, returns something you must release.

In this case, a quick look at the docs for `CGDataProviderCopyData` shows:

> **Return Value**
>   A new data object containing a copy of the provider’s data. You are responsible for releasing this object.

Please take a moment to check the docs before posting such questions. You will save yourself lots of time. :)

Comment: Thank you. I'm working from some code in a textbook that uses `CFRelease` for this case so sounds like it is incorrect. Would it result in a problem to use CFRelease rather than `CGDataProviderRelease` ?

Comment: Interestingly, `CGDataProviderRelease(m_parsedImage);` results in a function not found error with compiler, while `CFRelease(m_parsedImage);` works fine. In the same file I can use `CGDataProviderCopyData` without problems. This must be why the textbook elected to only use `CFRelease`

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: `CGDataProviderRelease` has always existed. Make sure you spelled the name correctly.

Comment: Relevant documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html

Comment: @PeterHosey note new screenshot in my question. It is strange; the auto-complete in Xcode suggests this function, but it simply doesn't compile. Other functions in the `.h` where this function comes from are working fine.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: What's the full error message? You can copy it out from the Build Log, which is among the items in the Logs Navigator.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: Oh, never mind, I think I see what's going on. You set `m_parsedImage` to the result of `CGDataProviderCopyData`, which returns a `CFDataRef`, so I assume that that is the type of the variable. `CGDataProviderRelease` can only be used on `CGDataProviderRef`s, not `CFDataRef`s.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: I think you'll find that the full error message is something like “No matching function for call to `CGDataProviderRelease` with argument of type `CFDataRef`” (meaning that the only `CGDataProviderRelease` that has been declared requires a `CGDataProviderRef`).

Comment: Ah, you are correct @PeterHosey. So in this case I should indeed be using `CFRelease`. So perhaps I should change my iVar to a `CGDataProviderRef` instead of a `CFDataRef`?

Comment: @SebbyJohanns Actually, I think this confusion is my fault. The use of `CGDataProviderRelease` is for releasing a `CGDataProviderRef`. But that not what you get with `CGDataProviderCopyData`. That gives you a `CFDataRef` so using `CFRelease` is correct. I will update my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: No; the function returns a CFData object, so the variable's type should reflect that.